# How to increase home Partion in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: partitioning

I have Ubuntu 15.10 with Windows in different partitions. While installing Ubuntu the following were declared:

- swap space: 65 GB
- ext4 - `/home`: 2 Gb
- ext4 - `/`: 200 GB

The Root Partition or My Computer in Ubuntu Shows 187 GB of Free Space.
I am unable to create Folder.

The Home partition has only 1.4 GB of Free space.
How would I be able to use the 200 GB partition for storing files( Create Folder Etc. )
I wish to increase the space in the Home Directory?

Comment: 65 GB is way more swap space than you probably need. 1½–2 times the size of main memory should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Get gparted but if you want to change size of partition in which ubuntu is installed then you have to make live USB/disk then boot ubuntu from this live USB/disk then open gparted and change the size of any drive you want. You have to use live USB/disk becuase you have to unmount the drive in which you want to make changes.